# Matching streets in two line datasets with PostGIS or QGIS?

Tags: qgis, postgis, shapefile, openstreetmap, linestring

Explanation:
I have 2 tables on PostgreSQL, one table named 'city' that have linestrings wich represents streets from a city (using QGIS I downloaded OpenStreetMaps data and imported to PostgreSQL using shp2pgsql).
[image: Linestrings from table 'city' loaded to QGIS]

The second table named 'round' also contain linestring wich represent routes from some vehicles (Using a Google API they were drowed).
[image: Linestrings from table 'round' loaded to QGIS]

Using QGIS I start visualazing how both tables look like:
[image: Comparing table city with table round]

When I made zoom to compare both tables I realized that differed alot in different positions
[image: Diference between linestrings]
My question:
¿Is there anyway to automatically update the lines from table 'round' so they can perfectly match with the lines from table 'city'?
[image: approximitation of what i need to solve]

Comment: QGIS has the algorithm v.snap. Not sure if it will work, but probably worth trying.

Comment: Try this PostGIS feature on copies of your data: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Snap.html